# Why doesnt the eye go along with the head?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I parented both of these eyes to the head bone but only one eye goes with the head
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the way you've named things, it's very difficult to work out what's going on! - The right eye (eye.001) has a Track to constraint on 'eye_bone_l' and the left eye (eye.002) has a track to constraint on 'Armature.002'! Similarly for the naming of the bones for the eyelids.

Comment: Im sorry, i updated the blend file. l and r are suppose to be left and right

Comment: You have only parented the right eye to its eye bone. The left eye has no parent. And because of this, it doesn't move with the eye bone and the head. -- I also recommend turning down the viewport levels of the *Subdivision Surface* modifiers. For render, you have only 2 levels. That's ok. But for the viewport, you have up to 5 levels. This generates over 2 million vertices in the viewport just for this character. It's a waste of resources and can cause a lot of lag.

Comment: Oh, and you have accidentally created extra armatures instead of bones for the eyes and the eyelids. Merge the armatures and give the bones and objects proper names.

Comment: As @Blunder says, the left eye isn't parented, but that also applies to the left eyelid and the left eyelashes haven't been parented to the eyelid either!